# What CSS to fix in different IE Conditional Statement Classes

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to find out if there is a summary for all the css fixes for the classes added (such as lt-ie9, lt-ie8, lt-ie7 etc) in the IE statements as in the code shown in Paul Irish's website: http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

if there is no such summary, do I fix the css issues (and add those fixes I come across in books/online) after actually testing the browsers ?

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Conditionally attaching those classes doesn't inherently fix anything—they simply give you a non-hacky way to target specific versions of IE in your CSS.

Comment: That article was published about 5 years ago. Nowadays, browser detection is considered as a bad practice. Try feature detection tool, such as [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of the time, you won't (or shouldn't) need the IE-specific classes. Writing code specific to a particular browser or version is considered bad practice in today's web; in most cases it is better to detect whether the feature you need is supported, rather than checking the browser itself.

This has a number of advantages; the main one is that it frees you from having to learn about all the browser features out there and which browsers support them. It also means that if someone visits your site using another old browser that doesn't have a given feature, your code will continue to work. But it also has advantages for making your code cleaner and easier to work with in the future. There is a library called [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) that does a similar thing to the code you quoted, but adds classes according to features supported by the browser. In fact, the same Paul Irish who wrote the code you quoted is also lead developer for Modernizr.

You can check IE's support for various features in various versions in either http://CanIUse.com or http://QuirksMode.org/css/. CanIUse is better for checking newer browser features, but Quirksmode is better for checking the basic CSS features as it has finer grained details.

Many features that are missing from old IE versions can be implemented via "polyfill" scripts. For example, http://CSS3Pie.com/ is a script that adds support for `border-radius`, CSS gradients and other features to old IE versions. A lot of the time it's better to simply let the browser do its thing and ignore the missing features (eg rounded corners are nice, but the site won't stop working if they're missing), but if you find yourself needing certain features and you absolutely have to support them in all browsers, there's a good [list of polyfill scripts here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) you can try (that list is provided by Modernizr, by the way, so they should all work well with it).

So for the missing features in old IE versions, you shouldn't need the IE-specific classes.

The only time you are likely to need the IE-specific classes is for dealing with browser bugs.

There isn't a definitive list of all known IE bugs (not that I know of anyway), but there are plenty of sites on the web that give details of them and how to deal with them.

First, make sure that IE renders the page in standards mode. If you're in quirks mode or compatibility mode, you may get issues. Avoiding quirks mode in particular will get rid of the worst of the layout weirdness that historically gave IE a bad name.

If you're in the unfortunate position of needing to support IE6, you will need to know about the various bugs it has and how to work around them. There are quite a lot of them, and being able to segregate those bug fixes so they only apply to affected IE versions is important so your IE classes will come in handy.

Later versions of IE have fewer bugs; IE8 is relatively well behaved and frankly doesn't generally require much in the way of browser-specific bug fixes. IE7 can still be problematic though, and IE6 is just horrible. The key here is knowing when you're being hit by a specific bug, and issuing the CSS fix accordingly.

For this, the answer to your second question is: Yes, you just need to test, test, test, and when you see something in whatever version of IE that is weird, you need to investigate it, work out the cause, and if it's a bug, deal with it as appropriate.

Comment: Polyform 'inserts' the features in case browsers do not support but still does not fix the bug right? so besides the Modernizr checking features, I should keep in mind of existing IE bugs anyway in case I come across it in future and I have refer to it right away, would that be correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, test in each browser, add any thing required afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

There is a service, which may help you to see css features support.

http://caniuse.com/

So you can see which code will make a difficulties in lower browser versions.